# Extend bars on a ggplot2 to show the data labels not squished

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

example_df <- structure(list(Funnel = c("Sessions", "AddToCart", "Registrations", "ShippingDetails", "Checkout", "Transactions"), Sum = c(1437574, 385281, 148181, 56989, 35613, 29671), End = c(NA, 1437574, 385281, 148181, 56989, 35613), xpos = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5), Diff = c(NA, 1052293, 237100, 91192, 21376, 5942), Percent = c("NA %", "73.2 %", "61.5 %", "61.5 %", "37.5 %", "16.7 %")), .Names = c("Funnel", "Sum", "End", "xpos", "Diff", "Percent"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

And here is a `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(example_df, aes(x = reorder(Funnel, -Sum), y = Sum)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6, fill = "#008080") +
  stat_summary(aes(label = scales::comma(..y..)), fun.y = 'sum', 
               geom = 'text', col = 'white', vjust = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=xpos, y = End, xend = xpos, yend = Sum)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=xpos,y =  End-Diff / 2, label=Percent), hjust = -0.2) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {l = l / 1000; paste0(l, "K")}) +
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The values on the plot from Shipping Details: Transactions are tricky to read because the bars are smaller.

I wondered if there was a good approach to dealing with this. I tried extending the range with:

```
+ expand_limits(y = -100000)
```

But that just lowers the y axis.

Is there a sensible solution to visualizing the data points in a way they are not squished? If I could somehow lower the green bars into the minus region without impacting the proportions?

Comment: You could add an `ifelse()` statement to `vjust` in `stat_summary` to put the label higher or lower for `y < 100,000`

Comment: That would help for the % data points, I was thinking about the white ones and somehow showing them against the green background

Comment: You can do the same thing for color: `col = ifelse(..y.. < 100000, "black", "white")`

Comment: For the above example, you also need `scale_color_manual(values=c("black"="black","white"="white"))` because "black" and "white" are stored as factors rather than the color values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very dirty solution, but works. Add dummy `geom_bar`'s bellow each segment (ie., extend original segment by adding negative bar) with the same color and alpha.

Bars to add:

```
  geom_bar(data = data.frame(x = example_df$Funnel, y = -2e4), 
           aes(x, y),
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
           alpha = 0.6, fill = "#008080")
```

Final code:

```
# Using OPs data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(example_df, aes(x = reorder(Funnel, -Sum), y = Sum)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6, fill = "#008080") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=xpos, y = End, xend = xpos, yend = Sum)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=xpos,y =  End-Diff / 2, label=Percent), hjust = -0.2) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {l = l / 1000; paste0(l, "K")}) +
  geom_bar(data = data.frame(x = example_df$Funnel, y = -2e4), 
           aes(x, y),
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
           alpha = 0.6, fill = "#008080") +
  stat_summary(aes(label = scales::comma(..y..)), fun.y = 'sum', 
               geom = 'text', col = 'white', vjust = 1.5) +
  theme_classic()
```

Plot:

[image]

PS:

- You have to add `stat_summary` after `geom_bar`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Looks great (Deleting this comment shortly)